# How do I store the output of a repeat loop in a dataframe

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

My basic idea is to compute the Means of chunks (column-wise) of a large matrix and store these Means as rows of a data frame. Note, the chunks have different sizes (number of rows) and these are stored in a vector `vec1`. Below is my code:

```
df <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(nrow = 4000, ncol = 3)),
                             c("Age","Weight", "height"))
#
i <- 1
j <- vec1[1] - 1
k <- 0
repeat {
    elements <- as.vector(apply(mydata[i : (j + 1), 3:5], 2, mean))
    df <- rbind(df, elements)
    k <- k + 1
    i = i + vec1[k] 
    j = j + vec1[k + 1]
    if (j + 1 >= l){
        break
    }
}
```

N.B.: When I perform the computations manually without looping it works. But the result of the loop yields a 4000 * 3 matrix filled with `NA` apart from the first row.

`vec1` is a vector with 4000 entries, and whose first 500 elements - `head(vec1, 500)` -are below:

```
c(15L, 45L, 111L, 32L, 25L, 13L, 144L, 31L, 150L, 124L, 22L, 
94L, 60L, 156L, 4L, 30L, 12L, 12L, 16L, 23L, 242L, 58L, 65L, 
17L, 63L, 193L, 148L, 162L, 79L, 6L, 22L, 30L, 188L, 44L, 7L, 
130L, 49L, 10L, 87L, 11L, 6L, 113L, 113L, 100L, 42L, 5L, 64L, 
127L, 73L, 36L, 13L, 120L, 44L, 34L, 153L, 10L, 35L, 205L, 31L, 
102L, 181L, 26L, 105L, 75L, 42L, 122L, 42L, 221L, 216L, 120L, 
50L, 171L, 56L, 1L, 89L, 11L, 103L, 167L, 96L, 31L, 67L, 182L, 
114L, 45L, 4L, 118L, 19L, 243L, 241L, 48L, 36L, 64L, 94L, 63L, 
16L, 8L, 213L, 26L, 127L, 139L, 71L, 91L, 133L, 23L, 88L, 31L, 
28L, 70L, 112L, 6L, 25L, 82L, 17L, 24L, 196L, 39L, 78L, 23L, 
73L, 110L, 64L, 87L, 84L, 11L, 101L, 19L, 6L, 25L, 39L, 59L, 
68L, 31L, 183L, 52L, 142L, 63L, 41L, 214L, 19L, 120L, 85L, 104L, 
3L, 8L, 38L, 11L, 12L, 21L, 12L, 53L, 37L, 85L, 106L, 12L, 31L, 
106L, 75L, 10L, 121L, 60L, 137L, 96L, 177L, 102L, 97L, 145L, 
52L, 11L, 112L, 73L, 67L, 8L, 235L, 203L, 182L, 168L, 101L, 144L, 
238L, 73L, 38L, 85L, 56L, 14L, 162L, 131L, 14L, 154L, 28L, 30L, 
75L, 88L, 268L, 169L, 255L, 127L, 111L, 63L, 42L, 156L, 12L, 
22L, 71L, 140L, 110L, 33L, 99L, 79L, 47L, 7L, 131L, 69L, 10L, 
61L, 2L, 57L, 96L, 111L, 41L, 250L, 77L, 22L, 198L, 187L, 15L, 
108L, 130L, 76L, 190L, 249L, 68L, 117L, 79L, 2L, 13L, 108L, 9L, 
39L, 42L, 43L, 149L, 62L, 47L, 66L, 85L, 197L, 109L, 21L, 263L, 
54L, 13L, 61L, 72L, 73L, 80L, 46L, 7L, 110L, 128L, 236L, 27L, 
240L, 61L, 23L, 82L, 157L, 92L, 95L, 6L, 137L, 237L, 2L, 20L, 
45L, 48L, 200L, 20L, 127L, 21L, 64L, 49L, 38L, 108L, 11L, 16L, 
108L, 18L, 62L, 15L, 61L, 81L, 28L, 20L, 33L, 50L, 222L, 267L, 
29L, 3L, 44L, 46L, 3L, 212L, 53L, 67L, 131L, 43L, 3L, 123L, 134L, 
106L, 91L, 194L, 2L, 97L, 43L, 39L, 65L, 96L, 233L, 36L, 81L, 
6L, 57L, 29L, 10L, 17L, 10L, 92L, 28L, 168L, 78L, 52L, 227L, 
86L, 134L, 58L, 65L, 175L, 20L, 113L, 33L, 143L, 11L, 87L, 101L, 
19L, 106L, 63L, 68L, 38L, 263L, 140L, 45L, 169L, 268L, 182L, 
114L, 88L, 39L, 6L, 53L, 244L, 84L, 99L, 46L, 53L, 1L, 111L, 
88L, 115L, 93L, 35L, 124L, 145L, 262L, 47L, 10L, 84L, 20L, 159L, 
207L, 102L, 48L, 79L, 28L, 51L, 77L, 3L, 58L, 20L, 81L, 54L, 
46L, 29L, 12L, 74L, 28L, 4L, 18L, 18L, 38L, 29L, 157L, 108L, 
94L, 56L, 23L, 92L, 60L, 86L, 39L, 59L, 85L, 14L, 53L, 23L, 88L, 
130L, 8L, 149L, 65L, 71L, 88L, 31L, 67L, 83L, 106L, 44L, 35L, 
23L, 76L, 90L, 271L, 12L, 167L, 30L, 87L, 3L, 7L, 15L, 159L, 
199L, 7L, 35L, 193L, 207L, 6L, 98L, 61L, 81L, 95L, 66L, 2L, 65L, 
242L, 221L, 51L, 6L, 5L, 265L, 119L, 126L, 7L, 159L, 74L, 63L, 
188L, 15L, 42L, 26L, 41L, 116L, 50L, 62L, 121L, 67L, 1L, 10L, 
192L, 59L, 42L, 84L, 187L, 26L, 32L, 35L, 60L, 117L, 227L, 20L, 
20L, 125L, 191L, 24L, 270L, 13L, 14L, 59L, 214L, 96L, 100L, 15L, 
22L, 100L, 49L, 146L, 137L, 257L, 93L, 91L, 23L, 234L, 108L, 
52L, 7L, 124L, 48L, 2L, 42L, 82L, 99L, 85L, 11L, 141L, 185L, 
30L, 1L, 269L, 83L, 25L, 187L, 122L, 222L, 11L, 201L, 95L, 40L, 
146L, 75L, 218L, 3L, 39L, 76L, 205L, 21L, 23L, 36L, 43L, 105L, 
89L, 10L, 155L, 32L, 144L, 160L, 181L, 144L, 139L, 5L, 2L, 26L, 
48L, 55L, 177L, 178L, 108L, 221L, 149L, 32L, 77L, 29L, 160L, 
115L, 23L, 193L, 113L, 1L, 154L, 87L, 239L, 221L, 36L, 100L, 
34L, 42L, 77L, 62L, 20L, 73L, 81L, 17L, 21L, 33L, 3L, 33L, 84L, 
92L, 31L, 9L, 65L, 187L, 62L, 87L, 48L, 218L, 6L, 41L, 90L, 102L, 
67L, 27L, 1L, 270L, 159L, 46L, 31L, 50L, 19L, 2L, 30L, 35L, 211L, 
103L, 12L, 99L, 75L, 37L, 99L, 83L, 49L, 38L, 125L, 53L, 29L, 
11L, 23L, 50L, 41L, 114L, 72L, 44L, 32L, 105L, 25L, 67L, 203L, 
24L, 82L, 167L, 205L, 28L, 89L, 75L, 52L, 36L, 29L, 16L, 137L, 
95L, 230L, 43L, 4L, 194L, 12L, 21L, 25L, 6L, 176L, 48L, 6L, 142L, 
24L, 15L, 101L, 160L, 43L, 9L, 125L, 122L, 53L, 55L, 226L, 241L, 
259L, 150L, 142L, 47L, 89L, 13L, 2L, 173L, 147L, 5L, 15L, 159L, 
7L, 27L, 117L, 97L, 38L, 71L, 7L, 35L, 91L, 172L, 149L, 103L, 
51L, 117L, 67L, 142L, 63L, 53L, 87L, 105L, 2L, 1L, 17L, 30L, 
114L, 55L, 202L, 34L, 70L, 50L, 37L, 167L, 45L, 7L, 102L, 238L, 
176L, 27L, 7L, 86L, 43L, 269L, 88L, 1L, 18L, 41L, 14L, 71L, 88L, 
144L, 44L, 19L, 189L, 258L, 76L, 13L, 44L, 20L, 152L, 133L, 86L, 
32L, 1L, 56L, 140L, 65L, 74L, 131L, 155L, 40L, 40L, 112L, 186L, 
178L, 249L, 42L, 184L, 43L, 5L, 13L, 90L, 111L, 173L, 220L, 71L, 
223L, 5L, 178L, 42L, 126L, 56L, 6L, 15L, 249L, 254L, 148L, 60L, 
133L, 218L, 111L, 29L, 77L, 16L, 71L, 128L, 100L, 4L, 13L, 72L, 
21L, 133L, 130L, 51L, 62L, 14L, 189L, 99L, 32L, 211L, 5L, 15L, 
35L, 72L, 153L, 59L, 85L, 165L, 18L, 51L, 21L, 123L, 15L, 93L, 
53L, 2L, 210L, 126L, 196L, 62L, 156L, 57L, 179L, 79L, 27L, 22L, 
52L, 167L, 33L, 150L, 72L, 30L, 3L, 65L, 36L, 89L, 54L, 18L, 
55L, 137L, 119L, 258L, 33L, 21L, 32L, 116L, 12L, 176L, 91L, 168L, 
74L, 6L, 4L, 138L, 149L, 39L, 47L, 49L, 81L, 35L, 61L, 4L, 58L, 
31L, 172L, 30L, 27L, 184L, 41L, 51L, 24L, 115L, 81L, 71L, 61L, 
154L, 206L, 182L, 149L, 42L, 49L, 6L, 104L, 2L, 217L, 27L, 148L, 
37L, 159L, 182L, 139L, 49L, 30L, 41L, 20L, 2L, 15L, 35L, 157L, 
86L, 261L, 161L, 145L, 105L, 87L, 220L, 12L, 99L, 233L, 190L, 
59L, 95L, 151L, 38L, 46L, 32L, 56L, 48L, 71L, 22L, 44L, 143L, 
34L, 34L, 7L, 20L, 87L, 106L, 114L, 26L, 7L, 110L, 93L, 113L, 
83L, 76L, 43L, 22L, 2L, 101L, 22L, 65L, 17L, 112L, 116L, 138L, 
122L, 68L, 5L, 247L, 155L, 149L, 4L, 49L, 130L, 46L, 13L, 223L, 
74L, 15L, 175L, 24L, 2L, 96L, 114L, 125L, 56L, 27L, 67L, 30L, 
206L, 38L, 42L, 9L, 118L, 24L, 11L, 156L, 109L, 154L, 40L, 175L, 
107L, 193L, 30L, 75L, 72L, 44L, 232L, 37L, 130L, 47L, 81L, 18L, 
120L, 126L, 93L, 51L, 138L, 6L, 47L, 76L, 65L, 91L, 14L, 92L, 
45L, 73L, 107L, 42L, 87L, 158L, 124L, 14L, 151L, 11L, 148L, 122L, 
36L, 169L, 149L, 41L, 152L, 116L, 122L, 39L, 196L, 124L, 142L, 
12L, 21L, 107L, 4L, 236L, 18L, 193L, 225L, 31L, 147L, 151L, 14L, 
63L, 12L, 79L, 55L, 198L, 7L, 84L, 101L, 22L, 194L, 150L, 5L, 
20L, 153L, 45L, 231L, 33L, 44L, 174L, 171L, 74L, 9L, 114L, 97L, 
107L, 7L, 87L, 113L, 49L, 14L, 32L, 1L, 43L, 131L, 43L, 22L, 
32L, 36L, 201L, 206L, 18L, 170L, 79L, 55L, 218L, 198L, 10L, 51L, 
35L, 144L, 163L, 255L, 23L, 180L, 20L, 40L, 89L, 107L, 82L, 67L, 
115L, 255L, 14L, 155L, 9L, 53L, 55L, 16L, 38L, 16L, 26L, 155L, 
4L, 154L, 147L, 223L, 57L, 75L, 54L, 50L, 104L, 79L, 145L, 71L, 
39L, 110L, 20L, 23L, 10L, 110L, 67L, 171L, 16L, 5L, 28L, 163L, 
204L, 250L, 144L, 101L, 18L, 36L, 139L, 10L, 102L, 57L, 125L, 
66L, 33L, 20L, 188L, 15L, 41L, 20L, 112L, 109L, 64L, 28L, 10L, 
149L, 196L, 108L, 26L, 173L, 1L, 58L, 185L, 35L, 44L, 37L, 106L, 
45L, 58L, 162L, 34L, 151L, 122L, 48L, 8L, 9L, 33L, 4L, 21L, 105L, 
36L, 32L, 133L, 55L, 87L, 18L, 18L, 6L, 46L, 79L, 113L, 17L, 
70L, 138L, 22L, 42L, 104L, 43L, 9L, 24L, 94L, 142L, 31L, 241L, 
23L, 2L, 86L, 62L, 36L, 80L, 2L, 76L, 89L, 160L, 13L, 12L, 4L, 
57L, 25L, 85L, 22L, 88L, 170L, 120L, 218L, 14L, 75L, 12L, 9L, 
198L, 225L, 139L, 75L, 1L, 6L, 35L, 23L, 67L, 19L, 157L, 68L, 
69L, 9L, 6L, 57L, 18L, 169L, 255L, 3L, 20L, 8L, 54L, 94L, 154L, 
34L, 151L, 52L, 68L, 85L, 107L, 9L, 232L, 165L, 50L, 153L, 14L, 
200L, 78L, 94L, 140L, 222L, 143L, 56L, 37L, 101L, 83L, 48L, 53L, 
38L, 155L, 8L, 132L, 148L, 39L, 53L, 151L, 3L, 5L, 59L, 3L, 56L, 
100L, 37L, 65L, 192L, 30L, 212L, 70L, 149L, 10L, 43L, 92L, 28L, 
97L, 20L, 105L, 133L, 134L, 4L, 65L, 83L, 16L, 158L, 168L, 119L, 
47L, 55L, 51L, 38L, 80L, 16L, 124L, 105L, 68L, 178L, 23L, 15L, 
177L, 146L, 71L, 7L, 2L, 36L, 7L, 3L, 89L, 54L, 42L, 67L, 133L, 
64L, 44L, 39L, 119L, 64L, 15L, 44L, 73L, 41L, 49L, 92L, 8L, 110L, 
167L, 59L, 224L, 102L, 23L, 6L, 69L, 126L, 97L, 240L, 21L, 32L, 
52L, 59L, 34L, 17L, 12L, 270L, 60L, 119L, 103L, 92L, 218L, 62L, 
127L, 15L, 65L, 64L, 63L, 17L, 135L, 67L, 49L, 149L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 54L, 27L, 167L, 7L, 8L, 53L, 72L, 85L, 47L, 92L, 36L, 158L, 
113L, 26L, 126L, 3L, 127L, 19L, 27L, 98L, 34L, 82L, 217L, 44L, 
105L, 104L, 65L, 35L, 63L, 82L, 41L, 167L, 12L, 136L, 52L, 205L, 
18L, 96L, 136L, 74L, 163L, 52L, 194L, 32L, 74L, 217L, 11L, 54L, 
228L, 33L, 22L, 51L, 42L, 52L, 8L, 235L, 250L, 38L, 130L, 126L, 
57L, 18L, 53L, 108L, 126L, 54L, 128L, 17L, 230L, 40L, 49L, 31L, 
38L, 42L, 18L, 14L, 203L, 114L, 73L, 226L, 4L, 4L, 271L, 48L, 
86L, 221L, 18L, 55L, 176L, 119L, 255L, 18L, 124L, 63L, 58L, 77L, 
159L, 118L, 116L, 71L, 123L, 22L, 38L, 61L, 114L, 114L, 1L, 104L, 
115L, 9L, 192L, 4L, 199L, 118L, 199L, 4L, 13L, 114L, 175L, 11L, 
39L, 189L, 30L, 113L, 112L, 13L, 102L, 11L, 26L, 130L, 2L, 47L, 
90L, 77L, 184L, 76L, 15L, 116L, 166L, 20L, 21L, 3L, 136L, 108L, 
106L, 87L, 60L, 78L, 106L, 18L, 45L, 85L, 41L, 11L, 85L, 46L, 
33L, 244L, 26L, 35L, 14L, 8L, 45L, 98L, 7L, 203L, 9L, 118L, 70L, 
85L, 178L, 23L, 8L, 29L, 221L, 171L, 67L, 106L, 118L, 95L, 216L, 
32L, 177L, 72L, 16L, 21L, 161L, 49L, 52L, 80L, 174L, 5L, 70L, 
41L, 43L, 13L, 238L, 5L, 70L, 128L, 152L, 53L, 128L, 18L, 19L, 
107L, 70L, 94L, 119L, 63L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 208L, 128L, 37L, 73L, 
8L, 166L, 243L, 216L, 137L, 115L, 178L, 32L, 31L, 49L, 13L, 4L, 
217L, 4L, 40L, 48L, 24L, 127L, 25L, 46L, 238L, 107L, 28L, 76L, 
54L, 97L, 104L, 9L, 142L, 4L, 32L, 21L, 46L, 36L, 11L, 75L, 175L, 
46L, 109L, 25L, 106L, 115L, 78L, 69L, 152L, 2L, 51L, 10L, 63L, 
142L, 66L, 168L, 78L, 11L, 147L, 271L, 90L, 88L, 10L, 143L, 71L, 
202L, 259L, 133L, 23L, 71L, 238L, 37L, 38L, 24L, 64L, 133L, 8L, 
194L, 24L, 92L, 25L, 230L, 195L, 34L, 162L, 18L, 69L, 75L, 18L, 
20L, 34L, 99L, 24L, 152L, 83L, 24L, 4L, 41L, 103L, 77L, 86L, 
23L, 46L, 53L, 63L, 98L, 54L, 17L, 122L, 9L, 25L, 237L, 71L, 
82L, 42L, 259L, 37L, 35L, 21L, 77L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 41L, 46L, 26L, 
100L, 265L, 224L, 45L, 68L, 263L, 136L, 243L, 109L, 122L, 25L, 
186L, 1L, 7L, 135L, 116L, 18L, 32L, 94L, 192L, 29L, 184L, 174L, 
41L, 71L, 14L, 125L, 61L, 70L, 178L, 90L, 7L, 14L, 194L, 167L, 
5L, 2L, 21L, 100L, 60L, 230L, 66L, 10L, 162L, 39L, 99L, 91L, 
65L, 22L, 162L, 139L, 43L, 230L, 59L, 61L, 168L, 14L, 23L, 73L, 
35L, 141L, 73L, 71L, 44L, 59L, 131L, 127L, 68L, 122L, 164L, 2L, 
17L, 111L, 4L, 34L, 147L, 33L, 11L, 33L, 54L, 48L, 235L, 136L, 
27L, 57L, 8L, 86L, 63L, 86L, 24L, 212L, 92L, 131L, 113L, 47L, 
132L, 5L, 175L, 12L, 51L, 81L, 29L, 232L, 126L, 20L, 157L, 158L, 
17L, 16L, 62L, 25L, 74L, 58L, 25L, 35L, 85L, 61L, 112L, 241L, 
135L, 183L, 77L, 41L, 12L, 101L, 12L, 25L, 113L, 38L, 28L, 95L, 
232L, 6L, 98L, 67L, 13L, 46L, 9L, 107L, 88L, 164L, 79L, 18L, 
13L, 200L, 20L, 152L, 107L, 40L, 31L, 146L, 121L, 75L, 6L, 237L, 
153L, 150L, 161L, 198L, 174L, 167L, 15L, 154L, 160L, 171L, 169L, 
23L, 22L, 187L, 226L, 40L, 213L, 87L, 269L, 136L, 153L, 103L, 
141L, 21L, 79L, 22L, 144L, 119L, 1L, 11L, 13L, 7L, 128L, 43L, 
77L, 50L, 142L, 79L, 5L, 182L, 19L, 39L, 5L, 63L, 228L, 13L, 
5L, 49L, 58L, 14L, 145L, 129L, 102L, 211L, 152L, 43L, 269L, 67L, 
36L, 10L, 103L, 98L, 83L, 13L, 25L, 155L, 11L, 33L, 127L, 79L, 
46L, 64L, 40L, 88L, 23L, 52L, 204L, 125L, 39L, 10L, 184L, 38L, 
113L, 123L, 68L, 69L, 126L, 7L, 36L, 43L, 3L, 243L, 82L, 50L, 
109L, 122L, 44L, 40L, 41L, 140L, 134L, 168L, 122L, 16L, 2L, 61L, 
37L, 73L, 163L, 70L, 18L, 9L, 205L, 12L, 89L, 1L, 17L, 119L, 
17L, 54L, 31L, 13L, 185L, 157L, 113L, 53L, 156L, 157L, 72L, 61L, 
29L, 52L, 69L, 23L, 261L, 51L, 118L, 48L, 98L, 49L, 250L, 29L, 
222L, 55L, 14L, 130L, 72L, 27L, 23L, 45L, 27L, 5L, 62L, 46L, 
208L, 183L, 32L, 37L, 168L, 39L, 47L, 3L, 88L, 74L, 40L, 254L, 
5L, 28L, 165L, 109L, 181L, 209L, 142L, 107L, 21L, 14L, 42L, 58L, 
198L, 30L, 91L, 175L, 108L, 18L, 60L, 86L, 6L, 82L, 26L, 8L, 
85L, 202L, 261L, 113L, 142L, 19L, 67L, 96L, 116L, 262L, 60L, 
55L, 47L, 56L, 33L, 39L, 196L, 77L, 10L, 86L, 142L, 11L, 49L, 
7L, 56L, 38L, 26L, 180L, 74L, 60L, 236L, 7L, 37L, 81L, 119L, 
26L, 7L, 103L, 38L, 6L, 184L, 153L, 90L, 42L, 22L, 140L, 57L, 
50L, 97L, 14L, 42L, 3L, 14L, 16L, 66L, 56L, 89L, 21L, 58L, 7L, 
101L, 16L, 125L, 224L, 64L, 110L, 20L, 5L, 67L, 57L, 161L, 271L, 
13L, 18L, 51L, 119L, 42L, 122L, 51L, 116L, 41L, 2L, 89L, 229L, 
2L, 45L, 22L, 180L, 3L, 127L, 195L, 8L, 230L, 203L, 72L, 203L, 
61L, 7L, 61L, 253L, 37L, 46L, 59L, 161L, 110L, 5L, 223L, 195L, 
45L, 1L, 48L, 163L, 3L, 56L, 76L, 77L, 107L, 183L, 7L, 30L, 145L, 
4L, 26L, 174L, 76L, 83L, 73L, 172L, 226L, 2L, 18L, 1L, 8L, 90L, 
36L, 8L, 44L, 36L, 90L, 64L, 89L, 127L, 24L, 67L, 7L, 263L, 71L, 
178L, 21L, 21L, 28L, 236L, 116L, 46L, 82L, 79L, 17L, 18L, 131L, 
49L, 90L, 65L, 168L, 93L, 2L, 267L, 59L, 35L, 126L, 35L, 185L, 
6L, 45L, 31L, 42L, 71L, 67L, 85L, 11L, 9L, 30L, 22L, 24L, 123L, 
119L, 14L, 98L, 31L, 101L, 137L, 81L, 47L, 79L, 4L, 167L, 78L, 
11L, 30L, 9L, 115L, 32L, 12L, 80L, 33L, 68L, 36L, 130L, 31L, 
7L, 169L, 54L, 9L, 155L, 61L, 250L, 89L, 149L, 2L, 101L, 66L, 
166L, 41L, 4L, 62L, 9L, 160L, 189L, 144L, 101L, 190L, 129L, 11L, 
124L, 22L, 13L, 151L, 1L, 58L, 173L, 195L, 47L, 3L, 3L, 24L, 
26L, 27L, 177L, 43L, 29L, 27L, 7L, 3L, 154L, 100L, 125L, 91L, 
212L, 224L, 77L, 53L, 135L, 2L, 11L, 65L, 60L, 115L, 78L, 55L, 
66L, 31L, 88L, 72L, 87L, 181L, 198L, 75L, 239L, 111L, 10L, 128L, 
103L, 68L, 27L, 127L, 4L, 24L, 102L, 3L, 19L, 103L, 268L, 5L, 
153L, 216L, 9L, 56L, 154L, 3L, 13L, 128L, 252L, 17L, 10L, 78L, 
65L, 245L, 53L, 166L, 11L, 28L, 43L, 85L, 11L, 179L, 200L, 127L, 
235L, 61L, 7L, 4L, 35L, 28L, 85L, 118L, 69L, 92L, 158L, 40L, 
91L, 104L, 165L, 135L, 30L, 230L, 121L, 204L, 44L, 106L, 5L, 
51L, 19L, 145L, 34L, 184L, 16L, 217L, 62L, 67L, 44L, 16L, 5L, 
39L, 13L, 16L, 95L, 158L, 43L, 93L, 37L, 47L, 33L, 18L, 178L, 
13L, 65L, 123L, 54L, 165L, 265L, 9L, 118L, 93L, 10L, 3L, 114L, 
13L, 8L, 48L, 103L, 160L, 92L, 135L, 50L, 7L, 38L, 16L, 64L, 
85L, 215L, 13L, 251L, 41L, 10L, 67L, 13L, 56L, 202L, 72L, 156L, 
249L, 56L, 38L, 27L, 15L, 177L, 39L, 36L, 62L, 53L, 86L, 62L, 
126L, 177L, 46L, 30L, 81L, 6L, 74L, 37L, 65L, 54L, 67L, 123L, 
66L, 144L, 90L, 48L, 173L, 47L, 49L, 108L, 22L, 103L, 22L, 144L, 
23L, 233L, 78L, 181L, 136L, 27L, 3L, 135L, 46L, 34L, 30L, 42L, 
6L, 53L, 49L, 180L, 247L, 106L, 22L, 124L, 9L, 161L, 43L, 82L, 
112L, 225L, 153L, 124L, 53L, 90L, 64L, 86L, 35L, 121L, 118L, 
129L, 39L, 3L, 16L, 24L, 224L, 128L, 145L, 108L, 124L, 32L, 9L, 
7L, 22L, 16L, 207L, 51L, 27L, 22L, 6L, 132L, 154L, 26L, 223L, 
145L, 105L, 78L, 44L, 171L, 29L, 53L, 229L, 89L, 47L, 41L, 81L, 
62L, 169L, 102L, 241L, 35L, 6L, 174L, 51L, 181L, 83L, 52L, 92L, 
31L, 110L, 148L, 52L, 7L, 73L, 136L, 25L, 29L, 42L, 84L, 190L, 
49L, 139L, 62L, 7L, 86L, 13L, 182L, 203L, 68L, 127L, 13L, 27L, 
244L, 69L, 65L, 92L, 14L, 257L, 7L, 49L, 20L, 44L, 17L, 13L, 
73L, 20L, 43L, 33L, 242L, 4L, 66L, 70L, 99L, 193L, 12L, 179L, 
63L, 14L, 53L, 49L, 105L, 59L, 113L, 79L, 124L, 35L, 9L, 7L, 
44L, 6L, 21L, 8L, 114L, 36L, 90L, 121L, 113L, 96L, 26L, 253L, 
14L, 53L, 10L, 25L, 18L, 18L, 10L, 87L, 4L, 159L, 179L, 17L, 
9L, 222L, 68L, 268L, 120L, 197L, 21L, 67L, 59L, 250L, 221L, 233L, 
41L, 114L, 20L, 136L, 136L, 94L, 19L, 29L, 11L, 81L, 179L, 154L, 
20L, 29L, 148L, 249L, 34L, 246L, 212L, 46L, 4L, 33L, 118L, 47L, 
246L, 116L, 42L, 91L, 60L, 49L, 186L, 37L, 85L, 8L, 26L, 5L, 
30L, 44L, 22L, 28L, 48L, 144L, 200L, 33L, 29L, 77L, 15L, 120L, 
33L, 27L, 53L, 126L, 183L, 79L, 62L, 102L, 61L, 112L, 56L, 77L, 
201L, 74L, 7L, 99L, 120L, 110L, 148L, 35L, 48L, 18L, 4L, 16L, 
84L, 53L, 39L, 20L, 36L, 159L, 30L, 3L, 46L, 247L, 31L, 127L, 
61L, 127L, 238L, 109L, 154L, 178L, 78L, 31L, 5L, 77L, 69L, 3L, 
49L, 165L, 91L, 29L, 72L, 24L, 30L, 105L, 55L, 225L, 28L, 36L, 
13L, 18L, 106L, 56L, 143L, 105L, 55L, 33L, 4L, 100L, 215L, 59L, 
169L, 103L, 70L, 76L, 189L, 42L, 94L, 101L, 41L, 83L, 52L, 231L, 
120L, 111L, 37L, 198L, 69L, 57L, 51L, 13L, 14L, 55L, 24L, 74L, 
136L, 1L, 218L, 110L, 125L, 26L, 106L, 203L, 46L, 57L, 16L, 90L, 
186L, 209L, 64L, 254L, 1L, 103L, 175L, 3L, 5L, 41L, 51L, 232L, 
89L, 73L, 67L, 260L, 85L, 189L, 249L, 166L, 72L, 250L, 56L, 2L, 
66L, 232L, 33L, 259L, 12L, 47L, 7L, 106L, 193L, 63L, 132L, 3L, 
21L, 76L, 195L, 15L, 43L, 171L, 29L, 108L, 84L, 199L, 189L, 98L, 
43L, 83L, 28L, 67L, 47L, 195L, 62L, 57L, 53L, 163L, 48L, 65L, 
188L, 3L, 52L, 257L, 62L, 62L, 114L, 38L, 128L, 26L, 205L, 100L, 
75L, 104L, 56L, 146L, 105L, 35L, 26L, 18L, 46L, 25L, 96L, 61L, 
1L, 91L, 13L, 169L, 35L, 54L, 77L, 35L, 9L, 213L, 124L, 22L, 
29L, 52L, 203L, 98L, 61L, 8L, 33L, 14L, 11L, 13L, 48L, 105L, 
76L, 22L, 136L, 123L, 18L, 39L, 39L, 9L, 212L, 11L, 37L, 9L, 
59L, 254L, 18L, 85L, 38L, 180L, 159L, 94L, 42L, 15L, 230L, 38L, 
35L, 19L, 98L, 185L, 10L, 24L, 103L, 67L, 8L, 63L, 200L, 135L, 
34L, 39L, 19L, 62L, 175L, 13L, 9L, 1L, 37L, 116L, 41L, 42L, 105L, 
54L, 17L, 90L, 47L, 38L, 34L, 23L, 105L, 23L, 57L, 115L, 107L, 
58L, 50L, 121L, 123L, 23L, 99L, 31L, 148L, 9L, 106L, 4L, 76L, 
55L, 102L, 66L, 135L, 43L, 73L, 7L, 255L, 15L, 24L, 229L, 115L, 
55L, 52L, 18L, 22L, 39L, 181L, 1L, 135L, 45L, 103L, 24L, 180L, 
118L, 228L, 219L, 116L, 90L, 154L, 35L, 73L, 65L, 48L, 58L, 35L, 
26L, 166L, 66L, 128L, 15L, 28L, 109L, 154L, 3L, 24L, 52L, 89L, 
50L, 53L, 69L, 17L, 15L, 124L, 50L, 134L, 267L, 11L, 194L, 6L, 
143L, 40L, 35L, 223L, 12L, 27L, 45L, 181L, 60L, 37L, 19L, 6L, 
24L, 57L, 75L, 12L, 93L, 38L, 27L, 140L, 32L, 57L, 115L, 82L, 
262L, 5L, 185L, 223L, 10L, 72L, 7L, 110L, 12L, 81L, 61L, 29L, 
91L, 12L, 85L, 62L, 34L, 73L, 27L, 16L, 85L, 216L, 228L, 157L, 
66L, 73L, 38L, 88L, 26L, 83L, 184L, 10L, 108L, 43L, 11L, 3L, 
47L, 61L, 139L, 10L, 8L, 69L, 11L, 63L, 224L, 82L, 5L, 22L, 3L, 
51L, 39L, 5L, 232L, 150L, 93L, 89L, 174L, 5L, 85L, 159L, 49L, 
150L, 187L, 101L, 29L, 20L, 48L, 4L, 142L, 44L, 57L, 105L, 79L, 
51L, 91L, 89L, 115L, 14L, 67L, 2L, 165L, 114L, 2L, 17L, 67L, 
38L, 108L, 23L, 103L, 223L, 1L, 34L, 21L, 41L, 73L, 186L, 55L, 
14L, 61L, 81L, 75L, 15L, 95L, 85L, 145L, 222L, 139L, 231L, 162L, 
79L, 67L, 80L, 75L, 17L, 27L, 48L, 38L, 27L, 71L, 100L, 51L, 
132L, 2L, 183L, 110L, 23L, 37L, 103L, 30L, 43L, 138L, 1L, 13L, 
83L, 180L, 27L, 21L, 236L, 78L, 118L, 93L, 95L, 83L, 28L, 15L, 
236L, 41L, 51L, 11L, 181L, 91L, 4L, 40L, 86L, 165L, 24L, 115L, 
252L, 28L, 35L, 13L, 15L, 7L, 9L, 27L, 33L, 9L, 40L, 5L, 105L, 
28L, 5L, 16L, 117L, 153L, 27L, 141L, 52L, 168L, 10L, 84L, 17L, 
47L, 56L, 233L, 140L, 69L, 221L, 19L, 8L, 71L, 37L, 123L, 137L, 
10L, 55L, 146L, 14L, 41L, 69L, 142L, 89L, 4L, 37L, 170L, 37L, 
35L, 182L, 70L, 24L, 158L, 83L, 25L, 38L, 116L, 132L, 209L, 69L, 
221L, 41L, 114L, 28L, 20L, 42L, 132L, 83L, 168L, 87L, 64L, 249L, 
155L, 66L, 113L, 44L, 35L, 100L, 133L, 31L, 126L, 10L, 184L, 
53L, 64L, 57L, 22L, 2L, 30L, 25L, 39L, 151L, 164L, 42L, 72L, 
2L, 38L, 29L, 8L, 22L, 9L, 91L, 58L, 58L, 78L, 82L, 117L, 104L, 
29L, 80L, 70L, 137L, 137L, 115L, 10L, 87L, 66L, 1L, 11L, 21L, 
118L, 262L, 70L, 5L, 153L, 118L, 35L, 249L, 68L, 38L, 79L, 30L, 
39L, 39L, 158L, 17L, 145L, 5L, 8L, 47L, 177L, 77L, 203L, 94L, 
107L, 96L, 68L, 7L, 12L, 24L, 18L, 146L, 13L, 164L, 54L, 73L, 
143L, 96L, 22L, 5L, 100L, 71L, 65L, 1L, 16L, 22L, 13L, 39L, 101L, 
39L, 75L, 148L, 45L, 257L, 67L, 18L, 50L, 62L, 29L, 222L, 96L, 
7L, 7L, 130L, 108L, 44L, 48L, 109L, 67L, 112L, 100L, 169L, 260L, 
130L, 169L, 79L, 111L, 121L, 15L, 21L, 240L, 220L, 56L, 8L, 18L, 
4L, 37L, 98L, 46L, 247L, 66L, 69L, 19L, 66L, 112L, 42L, 103L, 
122L, 155L, 36L, 4L, 60L, 39L, 25L, 2L, 182L, 105L, 157L, 5L, 
70L, 16L, 55L, 52L, 39L, 156L, 14L, 118L, 88L, 91L, 132L, 52L, 
18L, 38L, 31L, 35L, 75L, 186L, 45L, 110L, 232L, 52L, 135L, 33L, 
11L, 29L, 129L, 147L, 20L, 20L, 59L, 46L, 6L, 53L, 251L, 120L, 
192L, 41L, 87L, 38L, 134L, 5L, 120L, 130L, 71L, 121L, 84L, 183L, 
166L, 20L, 8L, 20L, 74L, 201L, 35L, 176L, 189L, 17L, 231L, 48L, 
38L, 3L, 142L, 53L, 199L, 135L, 6L, 38L, 256L, 76L, 6L, 56L, 
154L, 25L, 76L, 69L, 149L, 107L, 113L, 246L, 61L, 23L, 6L, 76L, 
3L, 68L, 70L, 89L, 130L, 226L, 31L, 157L, 24L, 80L, 170L, 169L, 
64L, 12L, 110L, 47L, 141L, 159L, 22L, 53L, 167L, 61L, 81L, 98L, 
172L, 261L, 99L, 9L, 13L, 132L, 103L, 16L, 97L, 186L, 35L, 128L, 
73L, 136L, 62L, 187L, 30L, 31L, 26L, 115L, 76L, 260L, 54L, 11L, 
169L, 227L, 43L, 6L, 23L, 212L, 23L, 68L, 119L, 181L, 34L, 137L, 
144L, 48L, 101L, 25L, 10L, 92L, 5L, 92L, 132L, 206L, 44L, 113L, 
9L, 25L, 249L, 69L, 250L, 67L, 35L, 6L, 60L, 251L, 6L, 32L, 94L, 
13L, 224L, 21L, 43L, 81L, 9L, 9L, 95L, 11L, 7L, 26L, 172L, 46L, 
17L, 3L, 2L, 39L, 26L, 7L, 18L, 57L, 88L, 16L, 47L, 136L, 135L, 
73L, 26L, 60L, 56L, 77L, 158L, 23L, 1L, 139L, 234L, 76L, 99L, 
28L, 22L, 83L, 114L, 6L, 122L, 7L, 36L, 59L, 4L, 33L, 79L, 25L, 
26L, 8L, 28L, 19L, 33L, 2L, 23L, 44L, 158L, 56L, 14L, 8L, 56L, 
16L, 36L, 90L, 18L, 22L, 7L, 74L, 70L, 2L, 51L, 13L, 130L, 25L, 
17L, 23L, 48L, 37L, 60L, 17L, 58L, 15L, 41L, 261L, 245L, 35L, 
17L, 41L, 234L, 13L, 11L, 192L, 3L, 5L, 29L, 14L, 34L, 4L, 110L, 
63L, 47L, 157L, 9L, 116L, 120L, 29L, 126L, 26L, 106L, 219L, 209L, 
93L, 255L, 137L, 88L, 96L, 87L, 229L, 23L, 128L, 101L, 62L, 2L, 
193L, 58L, 1L, 8L, 146L, 44L, 12L, 27L, 99L, 270L, 54L, 41L, 
161L, 231L, 53L, 126L, 139L, 77L, 55L, 32L, 6L, 159L, 131L, 54L, 
266L, 87L, 13L, 205L, 154L, 3L, 82L, 35L, 11L, 2L, 56L, 84L, 
110L, 116L, 28L, 30L, 60L, 74L, 12L, 147L, 31L, 206L, 31L, 56L, 
209L, 115L, 149L, 33L, 198L, 205L, 71L, 28L, 40L, 201L, 32L, 
3L, 40L, 75L, 91L, 32L, 9L, 4L, 192L, 11L, 41L, 30L, 46L, 57L, 
44L, 243L, 67L, 118L, 108L, 181L, 83L, 45L, 93L, 13L, 2L, 104L, 
163L, 92L, 8L, 17L, 14L, 150L, 5L, 60L, 123L, 100L, 105L, 110L, 
225L, 249L, 207L, 100L, 188L, 138L, 6L, 176L, 68L, 91L, 8L, 20L, 
18L, 21L, 79L, 20L, 4L, 99L, 136L, 28L, 156L, 7L, 36L, 226L, 
33L, 42L, 1L, 28L, 227L, 11L, 9L, 157L, 206L, 34L, 17L, 61L, 
113L, 112L, 158L, 24L, 18L, 36L, 75L, 40L, 18L, 183L, 3L, 37L, 
92L, 69L, 13L, 213L, 48L, 163L, 188L, 251L, 59L, 75L, 1L, 12L, 
46L, 232L, 13L, 74L, 32L, 149L, 219L, 22L, 59L, 109L, 264L, 25L, 
141L, 5L, 67L, 41L, 5L, 71L, 19L, 63L, 114L, 28L, 76L, 80L, 86L, 
71L, 18L, 166L, 40L, 57L, 185L, 88L, 115L)
```

Comment: what is `vec1` and how does it look like?

Comment: vec1 is a vector with 4000 entries, and whose the first 500 elements are:

Comment: Please use `dput` to give example data. There's no way for us to copy/paste what you posted into R to try to reproduce your problem

Comment: The problem is that your `if` condition is `TRUE` after the first iteration and hence breaks the loop. Otherwise the code seems ok.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you initially created 4000 * 3 `data.frame` filled in with `NA`. Please see the corrected code. I did not put your actual data `vec1` (too long) and simulated `vec1` with sampling from exponential distribution. Additionally I used `colMeans` as more effective than `apply`. See the code below:

```
# vec1, mydata, l - simulation
set.seed(123)
vec1 <- (sample(1:271, 4000, replace = TRUE, prob = dexp(1:271, rate = .01)))
mydata <- matrix(1:(300 * 300), nrow = 300)
l <- 300


# data given by OP
df <- data.frame(Age  = 1, Weight  = 1, height = 1 )
df <- df[-1, ]
i <- 1
j <- vec1[1] - 1
k <- 0

repeat{
  elements <- as.vector(colMeans(mydata[i:(j + 1), 3:5]))
  df <- rbind(df, elements)
  k <- k + 1
  i = i + vec1[k] 
  j = j + vec1[k + 1]
  if (j + 1 >= l){
    break
  }
}
df <- setNames(df, c("Age","Weight", "height"))
df
```

Output:

```
    Age Weight height
1 608.0  908.0 1208.0
2 638.0  938.0 1238.0
3 716.0 1016.0 1316.0
4 787.5 1087.5 1387.5
5 816.0 1116.0 1416.0
6 835.0 1135.0 1435.0
```